# VBA Fill Data To Another Column

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I will try to be as understandable as possible. 
So thing is that I have a classic form for data input which has 19 columns. Depending on complexity of the project, sometimes we have additional steps which needs to be performed, for my userform that means additional column. 
I have created the add button for those kind of situations, in order to add additional column in specific place in table.
Now problem comes with entering data in my table, as every textbox has its own predetermined place (column) where needs to store data, but when I add column it consequentially store data in wrong column.
My question is, is it possible to make if statement, that will recognize that I have added additional column and that will according to that store the rest of the data to correct place.
I was also thinking, if that's easier to fill the data based on the names of my headers.

```
Sub Submit()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim iRow As Long
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PFU")

If frmForm.txtRowNumber.value = "" Then
    iRow = [Counta(PFU!A:A)] + 2
Else
    iRow = frmForm.txtRowNumber.value
End If

With sh
    .Cells(iRow, 1) = iRow - 2
    .Cells(iRow, 2) = frmForm.txtID.value
    .Cells(iRow, 3) = frmForm.txtName.value
    .Cells(iRow, 4) = frmForm.cmbNatureIPR.value
    .Cells(iRow, 5) = frmForm.cmbStatus.value
    .Cells(iRow, 6) = frmForm.txtCity.value
    .Cells(iRow, 7) = frmForm.txtCountry.value
    .Cells(iRow, 8) = frmForm.txtGrantDate.value
    .Cells(iRow, 9) = frmForm.txtGrantNumber.value
    .Cells(iRow, 10) = frmForm.txtAgent.value
    .Cells(iRow, 11) = frmForm.txtCurrentOwner.value
    .Cells(iRow, 12) = frmForm.txtTargetOwner.value
    .Cells(iRow, 13) = frmForm.cmbDVStatus.value
    .Cells(iRow, 14) = frmForm.txtVerifiedOwner.value
    .Cells(iRow, 15) = frmForm.txtVerifiedApp.value
    .Cells(iRow, 16) = frmForm.txtVerifiedGrant.value
    .Cells(iRow, 17) = frmForm.cmbVerifiedStatus.value
    .Cells(iRow, 18) = frmForm.cmbRecAction.value
    .Cells(iRow, 19) = frmForm.txtComment.value
End With

End Sub
```

This is my code for add button

```
Private Sub cmdAddStep_Click()

Dim Table As ListObject
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("PFU")

  If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to add additional colum?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Added") = vbYes 
 Then
Set Table = ws.ListObjects("Table4")
Table.ListColumns.Add 12
Table.HeaderRowRange(12) = "New header"
End If

Call Reset


End Sub
```

Comment: Must the additional column be used for adding values like in the first code?

Comment: if I understood the problem, you have to store and use columns headers to directly address table column or search for them through sheet cells (with `Range.Find()` method)

Comment: I have in my mind a solution for your problem but, without some feedback, I would not loose my time...

Comment: So my goal is IF I add additional column between number 11 and 12, that every single column after number 12 be moved for 1. Other words textbox for filing data for target owner will in that case be in column 13 .Cells(iRow, 13) = frmForm.txtTargetOwner.value

Comment: I prepared an answer doing what you need, but on a different approach. Please, try understanding and using it. No need to move anything, if you set the appropriate tags to your controls. If you need further assistance, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications... I used 10 headers only for testing. You can use as many as you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not say anything, even if I think you should... I do not have time to wait.

I prepared a solution, working in the next circumstances: You can insert how many columns you need, **but you will NOT fill data in those columns** as you do in your first code. The code can be adapted to also deal with such a situation. Not very complicated.

You must build a string linking, on its logic, the column header with form controls where from the value is used:

```
strHeaders = "HeaderB;2|HeaderC;3|HeaderD;4|HeaderE;5|HeaderF;6|HeaderG;7|HeaderH;8|HeaderI;9|HeaderJ;10"
```

The building logic is simple: **the header is associated with the control tag**, separated by ";". Each header is sepatated by "|". So you must allocate appropriate tags to the form controls (starting from 2).

```
Sub SafeInsertOnHeader()
   Dim ws As Worksheet, Table As ListObject, strHeaders As String, h As Long
   Dim arrH As Variant, arrInt As Variant, El As Variant, Ctrl As Control, iRow As Long
   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PFU")
   Set Table = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
   strHeaders = "HeaderB;2|HeaderC;3|HeaderD;4|HeaderE;5|HeaderF;6|HeaderG;7|HeaderH;8|HeaderI;9|HeaderJ;10"
   arrH = Split(strHeaders, "|")

    If frmForm.txtRowNumber.value = "" Then
        iRow = [Counta(PFU!A:A)] + 2
    Else
        iRow = frmForm.txtRowNumber.value
    End If

   ws.Cells(iRow, 1) = iRow - 2 'independent of a control value

   For h = 1 To Table.HeaderRowRange.Count 'iterare through the headers
        For Each El In arrH                'iterate through the array elements
            arrInt = Split(El, ";")        'create each element array (header and tag)
            If Table.HeaderRowRange.Columns(h) = arrInt(0) Then
                For Each Ctrl In frmForm.Controls
                   If Ctrl.Tag = arrInt(1) Then 'for the tag matching the array association
                        ws.Cells(iRow, h).value = Ctrl.value
                   End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
   Next h
End Sub
```

If you need to use the new inserted column, during column insertion code, the `strHeaders` string will be amended with the appropriate `header;tag`. The string will be saved in Registry and used each time by Registry reading.

The next approach is even simpler. You will directly use the header name as control tag:

```
Sub SafeInsertOnHeaderBis()
   Dim ws As Worksheet, Table As ListObject, strHeaders As String, h As Long
   Dim arrH As Variant, El As Variant, Ctrl As Control, iRow As Long
   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PFU")
   Set Table = ws.ListObjects(1) ' ws.ListObjects("Table1")
   strHeaders = "HeaderA|HeaderB|HeaderC|HeaderD|HeaderE|HeaderF|HeaderG|HeaderH|HeaderI|HeaderJ|HeaderK"
   arrH = Split(strHeaders, "|")
    'I used your way of last row determinig but it can be done a little better
    If frmForm.txtRowNumber.value = "" Then
        iRow = [Counta(PFU!A:A)] + 2
    Else
        iRow = frmForm.txtRowNumber.value
    End If

   'Each control will have like tag the header name!
   ws.Cells(iRow, 1) = iRow - 2

   For h = 1 To Table.HeaderRowRange.Count
        For Each El In arrH
            If Table.HeaderRowRange.Columns(h) = El Then
                For Each Ctrl In frmForm.Controls
                   If Ctrl.Tag = El Then
                        ws.Cells(iRow, h).value = Ctrl.value
                   End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
   Next h
End Sub
```

So, for, let us say, `headerA` you must select `txtID` form control, press `F4`, in order to open `Properties` window, scroll down until you see `Tag` property and fill its value with "headerA" string. Do the same association for all your pairs `header/control name`, save the form and enjoy using it inserting columns...

Comment: Hi Fane, I appreciate your effort. But I suppose that I don't really understand the logic behind this. I've implemented your code, but I still have the same results like with mine.

Comment: Did you change the controls tags as in your `strHeaders` string definition? Do you understand what that mean?

Comment: I understand what that means, but I don't know how to create control tags based on strHeaders string definitions

Comment: OK. I will explain in detailes in about an hour, when I will be home...

Comment: So, the main meaning of the code is to determine a specific control for a specific header, independent of the column which keeps the header. Let us take an example: `txtName.value` must be written in `Header2`. This pair in `strHeaders` will simple look as `Header2;100`. 100 can be anything! Only to be unique between all controls. Then, you must go in VBE (Ctrl + F11) and select `txtName` control. Press F4 (for Properties Window) and scroll down until you see `Tag` property. Fill 100 as value and press Enter. Now the code will return the `txtName` value to `Header2`, for any initial column no.

Comment: @Tomislav Boberic: I can make the code even simpler. I will adapt the code in order to use as Tag the column Header, if you still have problems in understanding of .`strHeaders`creation logic...

Comment: @Tomislav Boberic: I kept the initial answer, to let you understand its meaning, but I posted a even simpler variant which should be easier to configure. At least, in my opinion... Please, do not hesitate to ask in case of something unclear. I invested some time in this project and I would like to see it functional... :)

Comment: Omg! :D :D this works man.. THANK YOU, I don't know which words to choose to thank you properly! This is fantastic! Can I be free to send you an email if I would have some problems in my future projects?

Comment: @Tomislav Boberic: Glad helping you! I have an email account on my profile (if I remember well...). If you do that, please make a reference at this task. Usually, I do not answer to people I do not know...